# Python FIFO 2 Dimensional

Tags: python, queue

How can I store static values 2-dimensional in a `Queue` in Python?

2 Dimensional like in C: `int static values[3][10]`

Is there a way do this in the FIFO way ?

Comment: Make a queue of tuples?

Comment: static in which sense?

Comment: `int values[3][10]` is two dimensional, not 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick-and-dirty

Example of a quick-and-dirty FIFO using tuples for 2-dimensional elements:

```
>>> queue = []

>>> queue.append((1,2))  # FIFO in
>>> queue.append((2,3))  # FIFO in

>>> queue.pop(0)  # Oldest element out
(1,2)

>>> queue.append((3,5)) 

>>> queue.pop(0)
(2,3)
```

### Using Queue

Using [Queue module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) which allows multi-thread use. Note that in python 3 Queue has been renamed to `queue`.

```
>>> import Queue    
>>> q = Queue.Queue()

>>> q.put((1,2))
>>> q.put((2,3))

>>> q.get()
(1,2)

>>> q.put((3,5))

>>> q.get()
(2,3)
```

### Using deque

Using [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as suggested by @Eric:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> queue = deque()

>>> queue.append((1,2))
>>> queue.append((2,3))

>>> queue.popleft()
(1, 2)

>>> queue.append((3,5))

>>> queue.popleft()
(2, 3)
```

Comment: Would be better to use `collections.deque` here

Comment: Didn't know about `collections.deque`. Good to know!

Comment: How can I print first 10 elements from this 2d deque? @DiegoHerranz